# Show user name on chatlist

Tags: c#, listbox, chat, guid, lan

I have created a lan messenger. It can connect to multiple client. Individual window is created to make conversation with each user. Popup on receiving is also done. But the problem is how to show user info like login users name to remote users. Mine only show tcp client object on listbox marked on the given image.Need help on how to get remote user info and insert it in chatlist.[Image shows my lan messenger chatlist. Circled mark is the tcp client object and one conversation window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D046J.png)

Comment: welcome to SO, what you need is a step after connecting the 2 clients, so that they identify each other. Works in the end the same as if you would send the message, Client 1 ask Client 2 who he is and client2 sends to client 1 a response with the data